# Add to cart not working in mozilla in custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, addtocart

Add to cart button in mozilla not working....

```
<button  onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
```

> script

```
<script>

 initObservers: function() 
      { 
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {  
        $('submit-editorApply-add-to-cart').observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));          
         } 
       }, 


        submitApply: function(event) 
        { 
         Event.stop(event); 
         this.option.apply(); 
         if(window.productAddToCartForm == 'undefined') { 
         var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); 
         } else { 
          var productAddToCartForm = window.productAddToCartForm; 
         } 
         productAddToCartForm.submit(); 

         },
 </script>
```

If i use `onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"`, than Add to cart will work, but i cant use this for some reason....

Is there any conflict with prototype.js ? or suggest me what may be the reason ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code was edited in View.phtml file related to cart , after replacing with below file , it worked in mozilla :

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
            form.action = url;
            }

            var e = null;
            try {
            this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
            throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
            }
            }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];

            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
            if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
            }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
            if (url) {
            this.form.action = url;
            }
            this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
```